# Как вывести из профиля пользователя wordpress дополнительные поля?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Приветствую. Есть сайт на wordpress в котором в профиле пользователя через файл functions.php добавил возможность выбора пола пользователя:

```
/*  Add gender in user profile
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------- */
function show_profile_fields( $user ) { ?> 
  <h3>Дополнительная информация</h3>
  <!-- добавляется ещё один блок в профиле, в примере он будет называться "Дополнительная информация" -->
  <table class="form-table">
  <!-- для того чтобы ваши поля выглядели так же, как и стандартные в Wordpress, прописывайте такие же классы как и тут -->
  <!-- добавляем поле пол -->
  <th><label for="gender">Пол</label></th>
  <td><?php $gender = get_the_author_meta('gender',$user->ID ); ?>
    <ul>
      <li><input value="мужской" name="gender"<?php if ($gender == 'мужской') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> type="radio" /> мужской</li>
      <li><input value="женский"  name="gender"<?php if ($gender == 'женский') { ?> checked="checked"<?php } ?> type="radio" /> женский</li>
    </ul>           
  </td></tr>
  <!-- закрываем теги и применяем функцию -->
  </table>
<?php }
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_profile_fields' );

function save_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
  if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id ))
    return false;
  update_usermeta( $user_id, 'gender', $_POST['gender'] );
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_profile_fields' );
```

А как теперь его можно вывести на странице (к примеру регистрации) ? вот так, например, не удается.. (причем опцию выбрал)

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
var_dump($current_user->gender);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот куда записали оттуда и считывайте:

```
$gender = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'gender', TRUE );
```

См. [get_user_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)

Comment: по вашему запросу пустой массив выводит.. в связи с чем у меня вопрос - сохраняются ли в базе таким образом как у меня в вопросе написано? хотя в профиле в админке изменения видны

Comment: Сохраняются точно. Посмотрите перед `get_user_meta()` что содержится в `$current_user->ID`. Еще добавьте третий параметр как в обновленном ответе, чтобы возвращалось только значение поля, а не массив.

Comment: в `$current_user->ID` содержится id пользователя, в моем случае 1, т.к. 1 пользователь-админ. Если честно, то очень сомневаюсь, что сохраняется способом выше, т.к. добавил через `$user_contactsmwthods['gender'] = 'Пол';` и все тогда выводится. осталось разобраться как сделать вывод через радиокнопки, чтобы результаты потом сохранялись в бд

Comment: Дожно сохраняться. Вы хотите на страницу регистрации добавить дополнительное поле? Может лучше в личный кабинет добавить? Вы заходите на страницу регистрации авторизованным?

Comment: и страница регистрации и админка планируются снаружи, ибо нечего простым пользователям по консоли вордпресовской шастать